# Places of a number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am reading the book *Class Field Theory* by Nancy Childress. In the chapter on Idelic theory, there is the following definition.

> Let $F$ be an algebraic number field. An absolute value on $F$ is a mapping 
>   $$\|\text{ }\|:F\rightarrow [0,\infty)$$
>   that satisfies $\|0\|=0$ and the restriction of $\|\text{ }\|$ to $F^{\times}$ is a homomorphism of multiplicative groups $F^{\times}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{+}^{\times}$ and that satisfies 
>   $$\|1+x\|\leq c\text{ whenever } \|x\|\leq 1$$
>   for some suitable constant $c$.

Then it is said that this absolute value induces a topology on $F$ via a fundamental system of neighborhoods of the form 
$$\lbrace x\in F:\|x-a\|<\epsilon\rbrace, \text{ }\epsilon>0$$

I don't know what $a$ is in the above definition. Is it any arbitrary point of $F$ ?

Comment: Yes: $a\;$ seems to be a generic point of $\;F\;$ .

Comment: Can we take $a=0$ ?

Comment: If you're interested in neighborhoods of the neutral elements (for example, to talk of topological group), yes. But in general I think you must assume  $\;a\;$ is a general element in the field and take *all* those neighborhoods as defined there.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, and $a$ is any fixed, but arbitrary point of $F$. The sets you mention are the fundamental neighborhoods of the point $a$.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that $a$ can be any element of $F$, but the idea is that we are forming an open cover of $F$ (topologically speaking), where the amount we require is dependent on $\epsilon$.

As an example, take $F=\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual (archimedan) absolute value. If $\epsilon=1$, then we can taking the set $\{k/2 \, : \, k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ forms an open cover (note strict inequality) so the system of $a$'s that we choose are of the form $k/2$ and indeed any rational is within $1$ of these points.

For a slightly more difficult example, consider the $p$-adic absolute value instead and let $\epsilon=1$ again. Take the set $\{ a=\sum_{i=-N}^{0} a_ip^i \, : a_i \in \{0,..,p-1\}, N \geq 0 \}$ as your system of $a$'s this time. We shall show this does form an open cover.

Let $x=\sum_{i=-N}^{M} x_ip^i$ and take $a=\sum_{i=-N}^{0} x_ip^i$. Then $|x-a| = |\sum_{i=1}^{M} x_ip^i| \leq p^{-1} <1$ by the ultrametic triangle inequality. (In fact the valuation is $p^k$ where $k>0$ is the smallest positive integer such that $x_k \neq 0$.)

Lastly, I wish to remark that whilst I have constructed such neighbourhoods, these are by no means unique; I could add more possible values of $a$ or shift them all by some random constant.

Comment: the set of half integers is not a collection of open sets. Additionally a cover is not the point, the fundamental system of neighborhoods in a topological field determines the topology, a cover does not completely determine a topology.